# How can i change jquery-div creation to some other method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I`m quite new to practically all web-technologies and I am practising on them at the moment.

On my new practice page i`ve created several things like this (to change div height according to the viewport height):

```
<script>
<!--
 document.write('<div class=\"head\" id=\"head\" style=\"height:'+viewportheight/6+'px\">');
//-->
</script>
</div>
```

I understand that this is terrible code. But it works. 
Unfortunately, jquery method .css for some reasons doesnt work. I`ve included code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js, but this one doesnt make any work:

```
$( 'body' ).css( {
    'width'   : viewportwidth + 'px',
    'height'  : viewportheight + 'px'
} );
```

I am sure that two vars of height and width have values inside them - i can output them using document.write(). I`ve also tried using constant values - no effect.

So, please, can you kindly describe how do i create divs with dynamical values without using script-tag every time or how shall i use .css method in right way?

Thank you and have a nice holidays!

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On my new practice page i`ve created several things like this (to
>   change div height according to the viewport height)

**Why use a jQuery or Javascript for this???**
You can do this simply by css like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
 /* style goes here
 ...
*/
}
```

In Web-development, you can always achieve all the styling of html done through jquery or JavaScript, if not css....but using it for basic styling or browser view-port is an overkill...( *like using a missile instead of gun to achieve your purpose* )

**Read more here**

- http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets
- http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

**EDIT:** (*for width*)

To understand how media-queries work,  [**check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/huLKa/)

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1500px) {
    body {
        background: grey;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    body {
        background: red;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    body {
        background: black;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}
```

change the browser view-ports width to see the body-color changing....in similar way you can assign the different `div`s, their style

**EDIT** (*for height*)

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/36eV7/1/)

```
html, body {
    /* set universal style */
    background-color:grey;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
@media (max-height:600px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
    @media (max-height:400px) {
        body {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        @media (max-height:200px) {
            body {
                background-color:black;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'll leave my answer up, since I think it answers the question more directly, but I think this is the better technique to manage the problem. If that makes sense...

Comment: OP is learning web-tech, your solution helps his learning, my solution helps him learning whats the obvious....we both are correct in our way!! :)

Comment: I`m now sure that i can use this to define values, appreciate your help to understand this. If i wanted to make 3 divs throughtout all my page width, i would do something like 1.)width:25%;2.)width:50%;3.)width:25%. That would work. Now i would like to do similar thing, but with the focus on height, which "doesnt like" percents. So, the heights of divs would be absolutely dynamical. With described by you method I can define their heights for a quite large segments of windows resolution (for example, for screen height of 900px to 1200px), but not for an every small change of 1 px. Am i wrong?

Comment: see browser resolution don't differ by just `1px`..they have a difference of more than that, be it for `height` or `width`,so media queries are created according to that.Also, height is not that much of consideration but width is when designing a web app/site.As for the understanding of media querry...i'll edit to show you a fiddle in work.w8!

Comment: @user3146504 : please check the edit...you should understand how media-queries work now...let me knw!! :)

Comment: thank you so much for your examples. I understand @media-thing for sure now. And would it work when i just for example minimize window and then just drug and drop the edges of the window?

Comment: it works for `window resize`....be it from dragging the edges or different view-ports,like ipad,mac,tabs and laptops! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

**Javascript**:

This essentially selects the element with the id `mydiv` and sets its `height` to `500`
     `document.getElementById('mydiv').style.height="500px";`

**HTML**:

```
 <div id="mydiv">My div!!</div>
```

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/t84X9/

Comment: I`ve tried to use document.getElementById('header').style.height = viewportheight/6+"px". Header is my css-class name. I`ve also tried to do this with getElementById('.header') but no effect :( i am doing something wrong.

Comment: well, your code sample above has the id `head`, not `header`. Is that it?

Comment: Everything is okay ;) i just edited the class name in my css, because it is bad when classname equals reserved name (i mean head-tag of every page).

Comment: I did wonder about that actually, although it's not on the reserved words list... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words